# LinearLayout child not displaying

Tags: android

I want to create the below layout.

[image]

Layout structure :

```
LinearLayout
  --> ImageButton
  --> TextView
  --> Button
```

What I want is to display the Textview's text center horizontally inside its parent layout.

But I can't event get there, right now the button is missing :

[image]

My code :

```
     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/toolBar"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
                android:background="@drawable/back_button"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                android:onClick="activityFinish"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/qaa_book_name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="xxx"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/qaa_end_test"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:text="yyy"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your TextView's `android:layout_height="match_parent"` is taking all the space

Comment: you can use ConstraintLayout or RelativeLayout or FrameLayout to achieve what you want

Comment: @RahulKumar if I set the button's width to like 50dp, how do I make the TextView to take the remaining space ?

Comment: put `android:layout_weight="1"` in your `TextView` property.

Comment: @JeelVankhede perfect, it worked. Please post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this **updated layout**:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/toolBar"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
            android:background="@drawable/back_button"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:onClick="activityFinish"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/qaa_book_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="xxx"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/qaa_end_test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:text="yyy"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

---

**Edit:**

According to [**LinearLayout**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout) documentation,

> When you set **`android:orientation`** to specify whether child views
>   are displayed in a row or column,
>
> You can set **`android:layout_weight`** on individual child views to
>   specify how linear layout divides remaining space amongst the views it
>   contains.

---

**android:layout_weight** : This attribute assigns an **"importance"** value to a view in terms of how much space it should occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view. Child views can specify a weight value, and then any remaining space in the view group is assigned to children in the proportion of their declared weight. **Default weight is zero**.

That means when you put weight 1 *(to `TextView` in your case)*, it'll take at least all space unless next to last elements *(`Button` in our case)* acquires space in container, So `TextView` spreads to fill all space once `Button` takes up space by it's **wrap_content** property.

Refer this guide by [**official doc**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear)

*Hope now, i make it clear !*

Answer (score 1):

`LinearLayout` supports a special property for its children called `layout_weight`. Specifying this property on one or more child views will make the `LinearLayout` first lay everything out as normal, and then give all the extra space left over to its children that have weight specified (and it divides this extra space based on the value for each child with weight).

The most common use case for weight is to give it to only a single child, effectively saying "give everything else as much room as it needs, and then give this one child all the rest of the space". That's exactly what you want here; you have two views on either side that should be `wrap_content`, and then one view in the middle that you want to have fill the space left over.

When you only have one child with `layout_weight`, conventionally you give its matching dimension (width for a horizontal layout, height for a vertical layout) a size of `0dp`. This is because LinearLayout still has to do that first pass to lay everything out before determining how much "extra" space it has left over, and sizing a 0dp view is faster than sizing a `wrap_content` view... and it's going to be stretched to the same size no matter what dimension you give.

With all that in mind, your layout should look like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    ...>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        .../>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        .../>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_image">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_back"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="xxx"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_yyy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="yyy"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_18sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/qaa_book_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="xxx"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

   Problem is in your text view {android:layout_width="match_parent"}  replace it 
   like this   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

The default weight of all views in a LinearLayout is 0. The least the weight of a view, the hightest its priority is.

If your put to a view : `android:layout_weight="1"`
while the other views are at default weight, then the views with default weight will get the priority. Their size in the LinearLayout will be attributed before the view with weight 1.

I hope this info helps you understand why a single line fixed your issue.